# How can I send a specific list item/view to Outlook as a new HTML message?

Tags: email, outlook, html

I've got a Sharepoint 2010 custom list that I'm trying to set up so that someone can hit a link in the list view and have it pop open a new email with the corresponding item in it. I have this working for *print*, but I cannot for the life of me find a way to do it for email.

I know this type of thing is broadly possible because I've seen browser based CRM tools that can do it, I just can't work out how.

(Just for the sake of disclaimer, I'm a total novice with Sharepoint and only barely experienced with code in general.)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can largely be done through a specially formatted [mailto](http://yoast.com/guide-mailto-links/) link though you will have to build that link somehow.

You could also add a [custom feature as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139873/can-i-easily-add-a-send-to-friend-or-email-this-feature-to-a-sharepoint-list) but that sounds like it might be a little beyond what you need.